Is the product of pressure and volume of an ideal gas equal to its energy?
While solving a physics problem book (Narayana coaching material Physics for Jee advanced volume 4), I came across this question.

An ideal gas undergoes a process in which $PV^{-a} = \text{constant}$, where $V$ is the volume occupied by the gas initially at pressure $P$. At the end of the process, rms speed of gas molecules has become $a^{1/2}$ times of its initial value. Find the value of $C_v$ so that energy transferred by the heat to the gas is '$a$' times of the initial energy.

Now my doubt is what the hell is the meaning of initial energy of gas. In the solution they are writing PV as initial energy.
So $$\Delta Q = aPV$$
Maybe because in the question they said volume was $V$ at initial pressure $P$
Whereas I used internal energy $U$
$$\Delta Q = a U$$
$$\Delta Q = a nC_vΤ_1$$
And getting different answer.
So my question is $PV$ really any type of energy. Obviously it is not Internal energy.

I suggest you show their and your complete solutions so it will be easier to point out the flaw in your solution and to explain why their solution is valid

$PV=nRT$ for an ideal gas.  $T$ is the measure of the average kinetic energy of the gas.  So, yes, $PV$ is the internal energy of the gas.  If you allow a small $\Delta V$ that is the pressure acting through a distance or the work done on (or by) the gas.  So again, yes $PV$ is the internal energy of the gas.

@Malcolm $PV$ is the energy needed to move the environment completely out the way of a gas, which is not the internal energy. The internal energy is $nc_VT$, where $c_V$ is the (gas-dependent) molar heat capacity. $c_V\neq R$.


So my question is $PV$ really any type of energy. Obviously it is not
Internal energy.

The internal energy of an ideal gas is considered to be entirely kinetic. So it’s internal energy depends only on its temperature, which is a measure of the average kinetic energy of the molecules.
Thus for any process involving a closed ideal gas system (one that exchanges no mass with its surroundings) the change in internal energy per mole, where $C_v$ is the molar specific heat at constant volume, is
$$\Delta U=C{_v}\Delta T\tag{1}$$
The ideal gas equation per mole of gas is
$$PV=RT\tag{2}$$
Which gives you (for a range of temperatures where $C_{v}$ is considered constant)
$$\Delta (PV)=R\Delta T\tag{3}$$
Substituting for $\Delta T$ from eq (1)
$$\Delta (PV)=\frac{R}{C_v}\Delta U\tag{4}$$
So a change in the product of pressure and volume is proportional to the change in internal energy.
Hope this helps.

You have some unit mismatches. If you plug $n=1,\mathrm{mol}$ into $PV=nRT$, it’s no longer $R$ there in the equation you give. Your last equation has joules on one side and joules squared on the other.

@Chemomechanics There's nothing wrong with PV=RT when its per mole and $R$ is the universal gas constant.   The error is the molar specific heat should be in the denominator on the right side of the last equation. Then it's $J$ and not $J^2$. Thanks.
